# Is It possible to have more than debug and release web.config versions?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, web.config-transform, web-publishing

I've got `dev`, `alpha`, `beta` and `production` environments. I store a few `appsettings` keys in `web.config` and use transorfmations to replace `dev-setting` with `production-setting` on publish. How can I do same things to replace `dev-setting` with `alpha/beta-setting` when publish on corresponding server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. You will need to create new build configuration for each additional transformation you need. See post from Troy Hunt [here](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html) where he is talking about config transforms among other things